# Reactive IP-Blocking in Nodejs, Node application security

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, ip-address, firewall

I am writing a client-server game in Nodejs, and I want to have a small anti-hacking, anti-cheating layer that can block or throttle detected hack or cheat attempts. The detection method is not part of the question, but once a Bad IP *is* detected, how can Node block or throttle further connections?

For example, is there a module that wraps the http server in which you can set a blacklist? Or a module that allows interaction with an external firewall program?

My background: New to Node, very much NOT new to JavaScript, PHP, C++, and C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind wrapping your core HTTP instance, you can use [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com) and then inject the [`express-blacklist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-blacklist) and [`express-defend`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-defend) middleware. However, they don't look like they're as commonly used as `express-rate-limit`.

If you don't need to blacklist and just want to rate limit requests there is [`express-rate-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) 
and that is more popular than the two middlewares that I mentioned above.

See the below middleware snippet for express-blacklist and express-defend taken from the above docs.

```
var expressDefend = require('express-defend');
var blacklist = require('express-blacklist');

app.use(blacklist.blockRequests('blacklist.txt'));
app.use(expressDefend.protect({ 
    maxAttempts: 5, 
    dropSuspiciousRequest: true, 
    logFile: 'suspicious.log', 
    onMaxAttemptsReached: function(ipAddress, url){
        blacklist.addAddress(ipAddress);
    } 
}));
```

Comment: Nicely within what I was asking for (thanks!), but raises the question: does express-rate-limit or express-defend interfere with socket.io? The game is a "real-time" multi-player shooter.

Comment: They shouldn't as they're not middleware registered with Socket.io but with Express and they should only affect Express routes.